# Nullable DateTime extension throws 'does not contain a definition' exception

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

In the code below:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime cleanDate = DateTime.Now.ToCleanDateTime();    
    DateTime? nullableCleanDate = DateTime.Now;
    nullableCleanDate = nullableCleanDate.ToCleanDateTime();

    cleanDate.Dump();
    nullableCleanDate.Dump();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    //public static DateTime ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime dt)
    //{
    //  dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //  return dt;
    //}

    public static DateTime? ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime? dt)
    {
        if (dt.HasValue)
            dt = new DateTime(dt.Value.Year, dt.Value.Month, dt.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

This line `DateTime cleanDate = DateTime.Now.ToCleanDateTime();` throws following exception.

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToCleanDateTime'
>   and the best extension method overload
>   'Extensions.ToCleanDateTime(System.DateTime?)' has some invalid
>   arguments

If I comment in extension method for `DateTime` `public static DateTime ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime dt)` error is not thrown.

Could anyone enlighten me with:

1. Why is this error thrown (aside from the obvious)?
2. Is there a way to combine these two extensions into single method?

I somehow expected `public static DateTime? ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime? dt)` to handle both `DateTime` and `DateTime?`.

Comment: As your answer says, `DateTime` != `DateTime?` because `DateTime?` is turned into `Nullable<DateTime>` by the compiler. Its a completely different type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not an exception that's thrown, that's a compiler error. The former happens at runtime, the latter at compile time. It's an important difference.

You get this error because the compiler can't find an extension method accepting a `DateTime`, only one with a `DateTime?`. Those are entirely different types. `Nullable<T>` has no inheritance relation whatsoever to `T`, so you can't make an overload for `Nullable<T>` accept a `T`, nor vice versa.

You can combine the methods by letting one call the other:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
      return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);      
    }

    public static DateTime? ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime? dt)
    {
        if (dt.HasValue)
        {
            return dt.Value.ToCleanDateTime();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Or you can just use [`DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns the same as your extension method and preserves the `Kind`, as opposed to the above code with which [`Kind` will be `Unspecified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx) regardless the input's `Kind`.

Answer (score 2):

If dt has datatype DateTime?, you can use dt.value.Month and dt.Value.Year etc to fetch the data

Comment: This does not answer the question.