# Show data week wise for current month in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I show data as per week in the current month? With my current code I am able to only display data either for last week, or this month, or maybe this week. But I am struggling to write a code where I can show current month data, as per week.

Example

```
Week1 = QAScore 94%(Average)
Week2 = 95%
Week3 = 90%
Week4 = 91%
```

Model Class as Below

```
public String Title { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreatdDate { get; set; }
public int ChatCountCreatdDate { get; set; }
```

Action

```
public ActionResult DisplayChart()
{
//initial data.
//List<Chat> orderlist = new List<Chat>();
        
//based on the year month and week, group the order, and get the weekly report.

    var result = db.Chats.ToList().GroupBy(c => new
            {
                Year = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
                Month = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Month,
                WeekofMonth = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().GetWeekOfMonth()
            }).Select(c => new ReportVM
            {
                Title = string.Format("{0}/{1}/Week{2}", c.Key.Year, c.Key.Month, c.Key.WeekofMonth),  //chart x Axis value.
                ChatCountCreatdDate = c.Count() //chart y Axis value.
            }).ToList();

//return the data to the view.
return View(result);
}
```

View

```
@model List<TicketTool.Models.VM.ReportVM>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "DisplayChart";
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<h2>DisplayChart</h2>
@{
var chart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 500, themePath: "MyTheme.xml")
            .AddTitle("Order Distribution")
            .AddSeries("Order", chartType: "Column",
            xValue: Model, xField: "Title",
            yValues: Model, yFields: "ChatCountCreatdDate")
            .Write();
    
    }
```

Above is my action method to display the data.

[image]

Comment: Please don't Capitalize random Words like This. Its is Very Annoying to read Text like That.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the function work and show Weekwise data for the Current Month with the below Code. Updating here, so can come in handy to others

```
public ActionResult DisplayChart()
{
/*This Month Begin*/

DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
/*This Month Ends*/


var result = db.Chats.Where(c => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= startDate &&
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= endDate).Select(x => new {x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime}).ToList().GroupBy(c => new 
{ 
Year = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
Month = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Month,
WeekofMonth = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().GetWeekOfMonth()
}).Select(c => new ReportVM
{
Title = string.Format("{0}/{1}/Week{2}", c.Key.Year, c.Key.Month, c.Key.WeekofMonth),  //chart x Axis value.
ChatCountCreatdDate = c.Count() //chart y Axis value.
}).ToList();
//return the data to the view.
return View(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the weekly report, we could get the year, month, and WeekOfMonth based on the datetime value.

You could create a DateTimeExtensions with the following code, it will get the week of month based on the special date time.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    static GregorianCalendar _gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    public static int GetWeekOfMonth(this DateTime time)
    {
        DateTime first = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
        return time.GetWeekOfYear() - first.GetWeekOfYear() + 1;
    }

    static int GetWeekOfYear(this DateTime time)
    {
        return _gc.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }
    static DateTime ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static DateTime ToCleanDateTime(this DateTime? dt)
    {
        if (dt.HasValue)
        {
            return dt.Value.ToCleanDateTime();
        }
        return DateTime.Now; // if dt doesn't have value, return current DateTime.
    }
}
```

> how can I show the above code in View ? Please help

According to your code, it seems that you want to display the result using a chart. If that is the case, try to use the [Chart Helper](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_chart.asp).

Please refer the following sample:

Models: The OrderModel is the Database entity, and the OrderModelVM is used to transfer the data from controller to the view and display chart.

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    public int TotalOrders { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDateTime { get; set; }
}
public class OrderModelVM
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public int TotalOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (using the DateTimeExtensions method to split the date time):

```
    public ActionResult DisplayChart()
    {
        //initial data.
        List<OrderModel> orderlist = new List<OrderModel>()
        {
            new OrderModel(){ OrderId=101, ShipCity="T1",TotalOrders=89, CreateDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 2)},
            new OrderModel(){ OrderId=102, ShipCity="T2",TotalOrders=92, CreateDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 9)},
            new OrderModel(){ OrderId=103, ShipCity="T3",TotalOrders=98, CreateDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 16)},
            new OrderModel(){ OrderId=104, ShipCity="T4",TotalOrders=99, CreateDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 13)},
        };
        //based on the year month and week, group the order, and get the weekly report.
        var result = orderlist.GroupBy(c => new
        {
            Year = c.CreateDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
            Month = c.CreateDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Month,
            WeekofMonth = c.CreateDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().GetWeekOfMonth()
        }).Select(c => new OrderModelVM
        {
            Title =  string.Format("{0}/{1}/Week{2}", c.Key.Year, c.Key.Month, c.Key.WeekofMonth),  //chart x Axis value.
            TotalOrder = c.Sum(d => d.TotalOrders) //chart y Axis value.
        }).ToList();

        //return the data to the view.
        return View(result);
    }
```

View page: using chart helper to display the report.

```
@model List<NetMvcSample.Models.OrderModelVM>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayChart";
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<h2>DisplayChart</h2>  
    @{
        var chart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 500, themePath: "MyTheme.xml")
            .AddTitle("Order Distribution")
            .AddSeries("Order", chartType: "Column",
            xValue: Model, xField: "Title",
            yValues: Model, yFields: "TotalOrder")
            .Save("~/Images/Chart01.png", "png");
        //.Write();

    } 

    <img src="~/Images/Chart01.png" />
```

[**Note**] In this sample, we should create an Images folder in the root directory.

Add a MyTheme.xml file in the `Views/Home` folder. This file is used to configure the chart, and the following code is used to display y axis value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Chart>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea Name="Default">
      <AxisX>
        <MajorGrid Enabled="false"></MajorGrid>
      </AxisX>
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Series>
    <Series Name="Order" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"></Series>
  </Series>
</Chart>
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information about using chart in asp.net MVC, please refer to the following articles:

[Create Charts (Column Charts) from Database using Charts Helper in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Charts-Column-Charts-from-Database-using-Charts-Helper-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

[How to add values to the top of column in MVC5 Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611447/how-to-add-values-to-the-top-of-column-in-mvc5-chart)

[Displaying Data in a Chart with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart)

Comment: Thank you for your response, and sorry could not test it immediately. I am getting an error when use the above action method "DateTime? does not contain a definition for GetWeekOf Month". Here is the code var result = db.Chats.Select(x => new
            {
                Year = x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.Year,
                Month = x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.Month,
                WeekofMonth = x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.GetWeekOfMonth()
            }); Kindly help

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh, Have you ever added the static class `DateTimeExtensions`? The GetWeekOfMonth method is in this class.

Comment: Yes I did do that

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514500/nullable-datetime-extension-throws-does-not-contain-a-definition-exception), try to change the Nullable DateTime to DateTime type.

Comment: Update my first response with the DateTImeextention method

Comment: No success yet :(

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh, Please check the Update in my answer, try to add ToCleanDateTime() method in the DateTimeExtensions, then, in the LINQ statement, calling the ToCleanDateTime() method before getting the Year, Month or Weeks.

Comment: Thank you. How can I show this code in View. var result = db.Chats.Select(c => new
            {
                ChatId = c.ChatId,
                //Title = c.Title,
                Year = c.ChatStartDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
                Month = c.ChatStartDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Month,
                WeekofMonth = c.ChatStartDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().GetWeekOfMonth()
            });

            var result2 = result.GroupBy(c => new { c.Year, c.Month, c.WeekofMonth }).Select(c => c);

Comment: how can I show the above code in View ? Please help

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh, According to your code, it seems that your application is a traditional asp.net MVC application, instead of asp.net core application. So, please check my Update, and try to use the Chart helper to display the chart in the view. If your application is an Asp.net Core MVC application, after using group by and getting the weekly report, you could return it to the view and use some chart plugin to display the chart.

Comment: Thank you, will surely try it and will update you.Thank you again :D

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh, You could also try to use the save method (when using the chart helper), then use a `<img>` tag  to display the chart. The screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjsU5.png).

Comment: Replicating your code works splended, but if I use on my Object it throws error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToCleanDateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." See my updated question above. Thank you

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh,I have updated my reply and delete some useless code, please check it. For the ToCleanDateTime error, I suppose perhaps the issue is related to the DateTimeExtensions extension, please check it, and make sure it contain the ToCleanDateTime method.

Comment: thank you. Code seems to not work when use on my Object. DateTimeExtensions are same as your code. Getting this error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToCleanDateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Before using the `groupby` clause, try to call the `ToList()` method first. For example: `var result = db.Chats.ToList().GroupBy(...)`.

Comment: Finaly got some thing work, but not showing  correct data. See my updated Action method and the image attached. Thank you a ton

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh, Please check the `MyTheme.xml` file, it seems that the issue is related to the **Interval** property for the X Axis, try to set the Interval value to `1`, screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LU9q.png).

Comment: List<Chat> orderlist = new List<Chat>()
                {
                    new Chat(){ ChatId=101, CustName="T1", MSTChatCreatedDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 2)},
                    new Chat(){ ChatId=102, CustName="T2",MSTChatCreatedDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 9)},
                    new Chat(){ ChatId=103, CustName="T3", MSTChatCreatedDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 16)},
                    new Chat(){ ChatId=104, CustName="T4", MSTChatCreatedDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 2, 13)},
                }; code works nice, but db,Chat.ToList() does not?

Comment: can this be because in myDb it also store TIme along with Date?

Comment: You can check the database to verify it.

Comment: Yes, in Db the MSTCHatCreatedDateTime has Time as well. How can we make this work in such case. Please suggest

Comment: I think you have to change these Time values to DateTime format. Because, you want to get the week report, it need to the DateTime data type (in server database, the column type should be `datetime2(7)`), try to change it through [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/quickstarts/ssms-connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Finaly made the code work, and show data WeekWise  on Graph. But, how can I include last months days in this months Days as the Week for April 2021 starts on March 29th. Any suggestion on this.

Comment: Hi @Zhi Lv Updated my answer, but April month is not including Date from March 29th Onward. How can March 29th be considered in April First week. Kindly suggest